# xslt xml to html fails when DTD present

Tags: xml, xslt

this might fall to category knowing the basics but I could not find spot on answer to this so I would appreciate push to the right direction with this.

I can see the printout in my browser (Chrome) when DTD is removed.
The XML that works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

    <recipes>
    <recipe is="test">  
    <ind1>Test1</ind1>
    <ind2>Test2</ind2>
    </recipe>
    </recipes>
```

The XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
 <xsl:for-each select="recipes/recipe">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="ind1"/></h2>
      </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fine and dandy, however with this XML it will fail producing only blank screen:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE recipes SYSTEM "recipes.dtd">
<recipes>
    <recipe is="test">  
        <ind1>Test1</ind1>
        <ind2>Test2</ind2>
    </recipe>
</recipes>
```

The DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT recipes (recipe*)>
<!ELEMENT recipe (ind1,ind2)>       
<!ELEMENT ind1 (#PCDATA|recipe*)>
<!ELEMENT ind2 (#PCDATA|recipe*)>
```

If I understood all what I learned this far the DTD is the way to go but theres something fundamental missing and I would appreciate if you could point the elephant in the living room and help me advance.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is the DTD in a place where your browser can access it?

Comment: You need to show the DTD file as well as it probably defines some default XML namespace declaration.

Comment: Added the DTD and noticed that I have no declarations in it. I'll run some tests... fixed the DTD too

Comment: No luck. I tried to reference the DTD with absolute path too but no result. It works only when I remove the DTD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML isn't valid with respect to your DTD (attribute `is` is missing), and the DTD contains errors in the declaration of the mixed-contents elements ind1 and ind2. Using the following DTD, I was able to apply your transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT recipes (recipe*)>
<!ELEMENT recipe (ind1,ind2)>   
<!ATTLIST recipe is CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT ind1 (#PCDATA|recipe)*>
<!ELEMENT ind2 (#PCDATA|recipe)*>
```

Comment: I have to school myself more with DTD then. Thanks for helping a n00b out.